# Rails -- How to write a link which will be called to call a action with a parameter in controller ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes, slim-lang

Example, in my controller:

```
class GymController < ApplicatoinController
  def store(page)
     ...
  end
end
```

And now, I want call this action by a link in `gym.html.slim`:

```
- a ...
```

but how to call it by link format, and how to write `route.rb` file?

Comment: What is `page` doing in the definition of your action? I have never seen anything like that. Do controller actions take arguments?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh  yeah,  page is just a parameter name.

Comment: Then you can access it inside your action as `params[:page]`. Don't make it an argument to the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether your store page belongs to a single `Gym` object OR to a collection of it:

#### For a single object

```
# app/controllers/gym_controller.rb
class GymController < ApplicatoinController
  before_action :fetch_gym

  def store
    # ...
  end

  private

  def fetch_gym
    @gym = Gym.find(params.require(:id))
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :gyms, only: [] do
  get :store, on: :member
end

# gym.html.slim
= link_to 'Store', store_gym_path(@gym)
```

#### For a collection

```
# app/controllers/gym_controller.rb
class GymController < ApplicatoinController
  def store
    # ...
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :gyms, only: [] do
  get :store, on: :collection
end

# gym.html.slim
= link_to 'Store', store_gym_path
```

Read more on [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) here.